# Import Cython exposed class from another directory

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I have a Python project in which I want to make use of a `C++` class that I exposed through Cython (really, I just need a specific instance of the class, as the code below will demonstrate). Because there were a bunch of files associated with the class I decided to put it in its own package.

In the `__init__.py` file of this package, I have what amounts to the following code:

```
from foo import Foo  # import the class

bar = Foo(some_parameters)
__all__ = ["bar"]
```

This works fine when I run `__init__.py` by itself. However, when I try to access it from outside the directory:

```
from qux import bar  # inside main.py in the parent directory
```

I get the error traced back to the *same* `__init__.py`:

```
File "D:\path\to\qux\\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from foo import Foo
ImportError: No module named 'foo'
```

Recall that `foo` is a Cython file, not pure Python code.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
main_project\
  main.py
  (more supporting files here)
  qux\
    __init__.py
    cy_foo.cpp
    cy_foo.pyx
    foo.cpp
    foo.h
    foo.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
    (more supporting files here)
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with `Cython` per se, rather, this issue is due to the fact that when you execute `main.py` in the top level directory, `Python` will execute `__init__.py` and search in the same directory failing to locate the `foo` module inside `qux`.

As a solution, change the `import` statement in `__init__.py` to:

```
from qux.foo import Foo
```

If for some reason you still need to run `__init__.py` as the `__main__` script, you can use the oh so familiar `if` clause to check the `__name__`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from foo import Foo
else:
    from qux.foo import Foo

bar = Foo("arguments")
__all__ = ["bar"]
```

Now, if run as the `__main__` module, `__init__.py` will find `foo`, if not, it allows others to find it.

Comment: That did fix it! I guess I was trying to do the equivalent of something like `import scipy; from optimize import brentq` without qualifying `optimize` as belonging to `scipy`. It just didn't occur to me that Python would still be searching in the top directory while running a script in a subdirectory.